# Find inverse of a matrix

Tags: matrices

What is the inverse of this matrix-

$M= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1&0&0&1 \\ 1 & -1&-1&-1&0&1\\ 1&-1&1&0&-1&-1\\ 1&-1&0&1&1&0\\ 1&1&-1&-1&1& 0\\ 1&1&0&1&-1&-1 \end{pmatrix} $

This looks like a tedious one. What is the fastest way to get this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use the fact that $AI=A$

Now, do row or column operations on $I$ in $LHS$ and $A$ in $RHS$ to get $I$ in $RH$S.
Then, whatever you end up in $LHS$ will be $AA^{-1}$

Comment: I'm not certain, but I _assume_ that that's exactly the approach that the OP thought looked like a tedious one.